# Debugging Bluemix remotely from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, remote-debugging, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud-tools

I tried to do remote debug of a Bluemix application in Eclipse. I enabled application debug. Then I did debug to Server but my Bluemix server didn't appear in the list. A local Liberty server appears and I can debug on that but not on my Bluemix server. I tried to create a new server with the same address in the dialogue but then it complains that the server and space already exists. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

W

Comment: I am having the same problem (local debug works, debugging on bluemix doesn't). [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054425/unable-to-debug-liberty-for-java-on-bluemix-from-eclipse) solved it by switching on the debugging perspective. It didn't work for me, but maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Switching to a Oracle Java 8 JRE solved the problem for me, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998808/bluemix-remote-debugging-session-not-starting

Answer (score 0):

Liberty remote debugging is working fine with Eclipse plugin, so I suppose you are doing something wrong.

Have you successfully installed Bluemix Eclipse tool?
Check you followed the steps reported in this guide

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html

And then follow these steps to enable remote debugging.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/09/25/remote-debug-java-applications-on-bluemix/

Comment: Thnx for the suggestions. I did follow the instructions. And I can deploy to Bluemix with no problem. So it should be all right. That was I was so surprised when it didn't turn up as one of the servers I could select for remote debugging. It was actually an example from a Bluemix workshop I tried to debug. But I hoped there might have been some project settings  I need to turn on. But as deploy work it must not be one of the more uncommon ones

Answer (score 0):

The latest March 2016 refresh release has addressed the general debug mode issues, including the problem with IBM JDK in debug mode.  You'll need to update both the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix and also the Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry (see https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix for detailed installation instructions).  Therefore, I would recommend to do a fresh install with Mars SR2 JEE Package to see if the debug problem is resolved.