# Bluemix remote debugging session not starting

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ibm-cloud, remote-debugging, ibm-cloud-tools

I have followed the Bluemix/Eclipse instructions to setup the Liberty servers in eclipse. Able to do everything with the Bluemix/eclipse tools except for remote debugging.

Receiving the following exceptions/errors when I select the "Enable Debug Mode" on my application under the servers.

Tried a longer Debug timeout but that has not helped. Any pointers?

TIA

> [2015-11-30 07:16:56.832] bluemixMgmgClient - ???? [pool-1-thread-1]
>   .... ERROR --- ClientProxyImpl: Cannot create the websocket
>   connections for JavaMemcachedApp
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.exception.ApplicationManagementException:
>   javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the
>   WebSocket connection failed   at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:161)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl$RunServerTask.run(ClientProxyImpl.java:267)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the
>   WebSocket connection failed   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:315)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:158)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:296)
>     ... 8 more [2015-11-30 07:17:56.868] bluemixMgmgClient - ????
>   [pool-1-thread-1] .... ERROR --- ClientProxyImpl: Cannot create the
>   websocket connections for JavaMemcachedApp
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.exception.ApplicationManagementException:
>   javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the
>   WebSocket connection failed   at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:161)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl$RunServerTask.run(ClientProxyImpl.java:267)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the
>   WebSocket connection failed   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:315)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:158)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:296)
>     ... 8 more

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you've done the following:

1. Enabled & configured the **debug** App Management utility as indicated here (1).
2. Ensure that **dev mode** for Eclipse Tools is enabled as indicated here (2).
3. Enable **Remote Debug** in Eclipse Tools as indicate here (3).

(1) https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_management.html#Utilities

(2) https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_management.html#devmode

(3) https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#remotedebug

Comment: Thanks Randal, for the guidance but still facing the same issue.
In the logs for my App I am seeing the following error:

** ERROR: [PacketDispatcher.cpp:95] Run: Exception in connection: TransportException [510/203] 'JDWP-Handshake' receiving error: timeout occurred ** TIA

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Let me try one or two things and I will get back with you.

Comment: Another observation - once I receive this error I cannot use the devconsole/shell  i.e., when I use the https://myapp.mybluemix.net/bluemix-debug/manage  I get the following:Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /bluemix-debug/manage

This happens after I initiate the debugging session from eclipse.....before that shell works without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happens to be using IBM JDK to launch the workbench?  There is an existing problem that we are tracking on the debug support using that combination. If you happens to be using that, can you try using an Orcale JDK 8 to see if that resolves the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help - Use of ORACLE JRE 8 Resolved the issue.

Comment: The latest March 2016 refresh release has addressed the general debug mode issues, including the problem with IBM JDK in debug mode. You'll need to update both the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix and also the Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry (see https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix for detailed installation instructions). Therefore, I would recommend to do a fresh install with Mars SR2 JEE Package to see if the debug problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the JDK in use .... replaced the ORACLE JDK 7 with ORACLE JRE 8 and that resolved the issue.

Regards
RS