# Bluemix with Tomcat runtime debug in Eclipse failed

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, ibm-cloud

I get the same problem as [Bluemix remote debugging session not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998808/bluemix-remote-debugging-session-not-starting)
 when trying to debug my web app on Bluemix Tomcat server from Eclipse, following the steps below.

1. Fresh installed eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64 and all
   required Eclipse plugins (e.g., the Eclipse tools for Bluemix for Neon,).
2. Created a new Cloud Foundry App in Bluemix, selected
   Tomcat as runtime, then Add Git and build and deploy the sample web
   app which called 'TomcatHelloWorldApp'.
3. Clone the
   'TomcatHelloWorldApp' web app to my Eclipse from Jazz Git
   repository.
4. Created new IBM Bluemix server in Eclipse, add
   and push the 'TomcatHelloWorldApp' web app.
5. Right check the web app under the IBM Bluemix server and select 'Enable Application Debug'.

But, I get the error below. It doesn't work even with the default web app created by Bluemix:

```
[2016-07-17 14:15:54.854] bluemixMgmgClient - ???? [pool-1-thread-1] .... ERROR --- ClientProxyImpl: Cannot create the websocket connections for asmilk
com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.exception.ApplicationManagementException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [500] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl$RunServerTask.run(ClientProxyImpl.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [500] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:158)
    ... 6 more
[2016-07-17 14:16:11.938] bluemixMgmgClient - ???? [pool-1-thread-1] .... ERROR --- ClientProxyImpl: Cannot create the websocket connections for asmilk
com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.exception.ApplicationManagementException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [500] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl$RunServerTask.run(ClientProxyImpl.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [500] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.impl.ClientProxyImpl.onNewClientSocket(ClientProxyImpl.java:158)
    ... 6 more
```

Then I try to modify the code and make it work fine with Java 1.8
Modify the Maven pom.xml file as

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Add below settings in the manifest.yml file.

```
  env:
    JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK: '[version: 1.8.+]'
    JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY: 'app_archive: {features: [websocket-1.1, servlet-3.1]}
```

Also modify the Build Shell Command as below

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/IBM/java8
mvn -B package
```

It builds and deploys successfully, and works fine with Java 1.8 now.

But when I try to 'Enable Application Debug', I got the same problem again...
Can you please give any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IBM JVM as your workbench JVM, the Bluemix [troubleshoot](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/index.html#ts_debug) doc has more details addressing this problem.